# Цикл For перестает считывать данные с ячеек (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Все доброго времени суток.
У меня такая проблема.

Цикл For перебирает и считывает данные с ячеек первого столбца,
по началу все идет как надо, но после второго вывода сообщения "Шкаф" он перестает считыватть данные с ячеек и перебирает их как пустые строки, тем самым не определяет на условие есть ли в ячейках слово "Шкаф"

```
Sub searshShcaf()

Dim lastRows  As Integer, lastColumns As Integer, i As Integer
Dim a$, b$

a = "шкаф"

lastRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row                               'находим последнюю строку в таблице '
lastColumns = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column                  'находим последний столбец в таблице '

Worksheets("КЖ_ВВОД").Range("A1", Cells(lastRows, 1)).Select                'выделяем первый столбец в таблице '

For i = 1 To lastRows
    b = LCase(Left(CStr(Selection.Cells(i, 1).Value), 4))
        If b = a Then
            Worksheets("КЖ_ВВОД").Rows(i).Select
            With Selection
                MsgBox a
            End With
        End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Debug.Print i, Selection.Cells(i, 1).Address` после `b=LCase(...` поможет понять всю глубину проблемы. Hint - не используйте Selection.

Comment: Внес поправки как Вы сказали, получилось. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Debug.Print i, Selection.Cells(i, 1).Address после b=LCase(... поможет понять всю глубину > проблемы. Hint - не используйте Selection.

В данной проблеме Selection лишнее, получается

```
Sub searchShcaf ()

Dim sShcaf As Object
Dim lastRows  As Integer, lastColumns As Integer, i As Integer
Dim a$, b$


a = "шкаф"

lastRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row                               
lastColumns = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column                  

Worksheets("КЖ_ВВОД").Range("A1", Cells(lastRows, 1)).Select                

For i = 1 To lastRows
    b = LCase(Left(CStr(Cells(i, 1)), 4))

        If b = a Then
                MsgBox a
        End If
Next

End Sub
```